# conditions for continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

A function $f\colon [0,1]\to [0,\infty)$ is continuous and satisfies

$f(0) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ und $ f(x)\le\int_0^x \frac{f(s)}{s}ds$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

I'm curious if it implies $f\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does indeed. First observe that $f(0)=0$. Now define $g(x):=f(x)/x$ for $x\in(0,1]$ and $g(0):=0$. Then $g:[0,1]\to[0,\infty)$ is continuous and
$$
xg(x)\le\int_0^x g(t)\,dt
$$
for all $x\in[0,1]$. Let $x_0$ be the *smallest*  point in $[0,1]$ at which $g$ attains its maximum value. Suppose that $g(x_0)>0$. Then $g(t)<g(x_0)$ for all $t\in[0,x_0)$, and so the average value $x_0^{-1}\int_0^{x_0}g(t)\,dt$ is strictly less than $g(x_0)$. This leads to absurdity:
$$
x_0g(x_0)\le\int_0^{x_0}g(t)\,dt<x_0g(x_0).
$$
Consequently $g(x_0)=0$, so $g\equiv 0$, and finally $f\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
 h(x) = \frac 1x \int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{t}
$$
is differentiable on $(0, 1)$ with
$$
 h'(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x^2} \int_0^x\frac{f(t)}{t} \le 0 \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
 0 \le h(x) \le \lim_{x \to 0+} h(x) = \lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{f(x)}{x} = f(0) = 0 
$$
for all $x \in (0, 1)$. So $h$ is identically zero, and that implies that $f(x) = x  \cdot(x h(x))'$ is identically zero as well.