# How to prove that function is 0?

Tags: functions, continuity, indefinite-integrals

Let $f:[0,a]\to [0,\infty)$ be continuous function such that $f(0)=0$, $f'_+(0)=0$ and $f(x)\leq \int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{t}dt, \forall x\in [0,a]$. Prove that $f\equiv 0$.
I don't have any idea how to deal with this.
Any hint is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1648174/42969